# Vaadin table hide columns and container customization

Tags: hibernate, vaadin

I am testing a project, using Vaadin and Hibernate. I am trying to use the HbnContainer class to show data into table. The problem is that I do not want to show all the properties of the two classes in the table.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private UserRole role;

//getters and setters
}
```

and a second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
class UserRole {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

//getters and setters
}
```

Next, I retrieve my data using the HbnContainer, and connect it to the table:

```
HbnContainer container = new HbnContainer(User.class, app);
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

The Table will only display the columns from User, and for the "role" it will put the role id instead. How can I hide that column, and replace it with the UserRole.name ?

I managed to use a ColumnGenerator() to get the string value in the table, for the UserRole - but I couldn't remove the previous column, with the numerical value.

What am I missing? Or, what is the best way to "customize" your data, before displaying a table (if i want to show data in a table from more than one object type.. what do I do?)

If I can't find a simple solution soon, I think I will just build the tables "by hand"..

So, any advice on this matter?

**EDIT:**
I did not express myself to well before. What I need to know is how to use nested pojos, with HbnContainer, and control what properties (and "sub-properties") appear in the table. I tried to Extend and reimplement some parts of HbnContainer, but.. couldn't do it properly.

For the previous example, the table generated from the Users table looks like:

```
Name  |Role
George| 1
Alex  | 2
```

I want something like:

```
Name  | Role
George| admin
Alex  | user
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to define which properties should be visible in the table (thus excluding the role id). This can be achieved with the [setVisibleColumns()](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setVisibleColumns%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding column / adding generated column you can override `formatPropertyValue` method in Table class.

```
final Table table = new Table() {
    @Override
    protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId, Property property) {
        if ("column".equals(colId)) {
            return "something";
        }

        return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
    }
};
```

To get the POJO (in your case User object) you can use this construction:

```
User blogger = (User) ((HbnContainer.EntityItem.EntityItemProperty) property).getPojo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, this helped (hope it helps you too)

```
tblUsers.addGeneratedColumn("userRole", new Table.ColumnGenerator() {
            public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId, final Object columnId) {
                return new Label(userRoleService.getById(itemId.toString()).getName());
            }
        });
```